# Displaying Flash files in a node-webkit app

Tags: html, node.js, flash, node-webkit

I need to run a swf file inside a node-webkit app. I have the swf embedded, plugins enabled in my package.json file, but I get the error “couldn't load plugin”. How can I successfully run Flash inside a node-webkit app?

I'm running Ubuntu.

This is the package.json:

```
{
  "name": "nw-demo",
  "main": "index.html",
    "webkit" : {
    "plugin" : true
  }
}
```

and this is the HTML:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Hello World</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <object width="100" height="100">
            <param name="movie" value="file.swf">
            <embed src="movie.swf" width="100" height="100">
            </embed>
        </object>
    </body>
</html>
```

Thank you!

Comment: Is flash installed on the machine?

Comment: Yes. It's an Ubuntu machine, i forgot to mention..

Answer (score 2):

you need copy pepperFlash to folder plugins inside project. Also add this into package.json:

```
"chromium-args": "--ppapi-flash-path=plugins/libpepflashplayer.so --ppapi-flash-version=17.0.0.134"
```

If you are launching app with nw command you must launch inside app folder, same level plugin folder

You can get PepperFlash from google chrome, but you can't distribute application with this pluggin by license.

Comment: Do you know how to add global secure path of flash plugins for display local swf file in nw app ?

Comment: like http://www.macromedia.com/support/documentation/cn/flashplayer/help/settings_manager04.html